# Simple random walk on the $N$-cycle

Tags: probability, finite-groups, markov-chains, random-walk, eigenfunctions

I am considering the following example:

[image]
[image]

In my lecture notes we noted that "the functions $(\phi_j)_j$ form a basis". I think they refer to the space $\mathbb{C}^G$ where $G$ is the above multiplicative group. Now I would like to prove the linear independence of those functions. Is there a method to avoid the big computation?

Thanks

Comment: [Vandermonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) solved this.

Comment: @Did Thanks for your comments :)